# Google PageSpeed giving different comparison results to WebPageTest.org

Tags: performance, page-speed, google-pagespeed

Testing LiteSpeed Cache -v- Rabbit Loader to determine which is faster for my website;

`https://staging.webby.net.au` uses Rabbit Loader
`https://www.webby.net.au` uses LiteSpeed Cache

Google PageSpeed Insights says:

- `staging.webby.net.au` [loads in 3.5s](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-staging-webby-net-au/0sy68eid5u?form_factor=mobile) (Rabbit Loader)
- `www.webby.net.au` [loads in 9s](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-webby-net-au/iddji1rflo?form_factor=mobile) (LiteSpeed Cache)

However, WebPageTest.org says:

- `staging.webby.net.au` [loads in 0.939s](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/230518_BiDc4J_4D8/) (Rabbit Loader)
- `www.webby.net.au` [loads in 0.725s](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/230518_BiDcYS_4DD/) (LiteSpeed Cache)

Why is Google PageSpeed Insights indicating the website cached with Rabbit Loader faster than with LiteSpeed Cache, but WebPageTest.org indicates the opposite?

Is it because Rabbit Loader uses a CDN, Google PageSpeed Insights is located in the USA, `staging.webby.net.au` has a USA CDN presence, while `www.webby.net.au` does not have a USA CDN presence?

The two WebPageTest.org tests are run from Sydney, where the two websites are hosted. Does this make it a fairer test, indicating LiteSpeed Cache produces a faster website speed than Rabbit Loader?